# Kill current LWP request with CTRL + C

Tags: perl, lwp

I have a script based on Term::ReadLine and LWP::UserAgent

The logic is like this,

```
while (defined ($_ = $term->readline('console> ')))
{
    next unless $_; chomp;

    if ($_ eq 'exit')
    {
        last;
    }
    &run ($_);
}

sub run {
    my $ua   = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $resp = $ua->get (...);

    say $resp->content;
}
```

In `run` it will do a LWP request. Now If I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, not only the LWP is terminated, the whole perl script is terminated as well.

I wanted to kill the LWP request only. Any ideas?

I can add a SIGINT handler, but I don't know what the handler should do

Comment: How does `run()` "_will do a LWP request_"?  Does it spawn a new process, or simply runs LWP and waits for the sub to return?

Comment: @zdim the second one

Comment: Please show the code for `run`, otherwise we will be forced to guess and will get it wrong

Comment: @Borodin attached a shortened version

Comment: Thanks. And please don't call a subroutine using an ampersand. That hasn't been best practice for twenty years. `run($_)` is correct, but your choice of name could be much better.

Comment: Btw, note `last if $_ eq 'exit';`, or `last if /^exit$/;`.  Fits nicely with `next unless ...`.  With regex it can also come before `chomp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the signal into an exception.

```
local $SIG{INT} = sub { die "SIGINT\n" };
```

Generally, one would then wrap the code in an `eval BLOCK`, but LWP::UserAgent catches these exceptions and returns an error response.

For example,

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = do {
   local $SIG{INT} = sub { die "SIGINT\n" };
   $ua->get("http://localhost/zzz.crx")
};
say $response->is_success ? "Successful" : "Unsuccessful";
say $response->code;
say $response->status_line;
```

Output if no SIGINT received:

```
Successful
200
200 OK
```

Output if SIGINT received:

```
Unsuccessful
500
500 SIGINT
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to stop code is to run it in a child process and `kill` that child in the parent's signal handler when `SIGINT` is received by the parent.  The parent keeps running since the signal is handled.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

$SIG{INT} = \&sigint_handler;    # or: $SIG{INT} = sub { ... };

say "Parent $$ start.";

my $pid = run_proc();
my $gone_pid = waitpid $pid, 0;  # check status, in $?

say "Parent exiting";

sub run_proc
{
    my $pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";
    if ($pid == 0) {                               # child process
        say "\tKid, sleep 5 (time for Ctrl-C)";    # run your job here
        sleep 5;                                
        say "\tKid exiting.";
        exit;
    }   
    return $pid;
}

sub sigint_handler { 
    if ($pid and kill 0, $pid) {
        say "Got $_[0], send 'kill TERM' to child process $pid.";
        my $no_signalled = kill 15, $pid;
     }
     else { die "Got $_[0]" }   # or use exit
}
```

A good deal of the code is for diagnostic prints. Some comments follow

The `kill` only sends a signal. It does not in any way ensure that the process terminates. Check this with `kill $pid, 0`, which  returns true if the process has not *been reaped* (even if it's a zombie). On my system `TERM` is `15`, and even though this is very common please check.

The signal could come at a time when the child is not running. The handler first checks whether the `$pid` is out there and if not it dies/exits, respecting `SIGINT`. Change as appropriate.

After the `fork` the parent drops past `if ($pid == 0)` and returns the `$pid` right away.

You can install `$SIG{TERM}` *in the child*, where it can clean up if it needs to exit orderly.

The `SIGINT` handler will run out of the child as well, so `"Got $_[0] ..."` is printed twice. If this is a concern add a handler to the child to ignore the signal, `$SIG{INT} = 'IGNORE';`. With this in place and with Ctrl-C hit while the child is running, the output is

```
Parent 9334 start.
        Kid, sleep 5 (time for Ctrl-C)
^CGot INT, send 'kill TERM' to child process 9335.
Parent exiting
```

The status of the child once it exited can be checked via `$?`, see `system` and [in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables).

Documentation: [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) (and [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html), [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)), [%SIG in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25SIG), [waitpid](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html),  parts of [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html), [kill](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html).

If the job done in the child needed to communicate with the parent then there would be more to do. However, the code snippet added to the question indicates that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a callback in your call to `$ua->request`. Issuing `die` in that callback will terminate the transfer.

You then just need to set a flag variable in your Ctrl-C signal handler, and `die` in your callback if that flag is set.

I'll write some code when I get back to a PC, and when you have shown what your `run` subroutine does.

---

Here's some code that looks right, but I can't test it at present

*Beware that `run` is a dire identifier for any subroutine, especially one that starts a network transfer and prints the result*

```
sub run {

    my ($url) = @_;

    my $die;
    local $SIG{INT} = sub { $die = 1 };

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

    my $resp = $ua->get(
        $url,
        ':content_cb' => sub {
            die "Interrupted LWP transfer" if $die;
            my ($data, $resp, $proto) = @_;
            print $data;
        },
        ':read_size_hint' => 1024
    );

    print "\n";  # Emulate additional newline from `say`
}
```

Note that  reducing `:read_size_hint` will cause the callback to be called more frequently with smaller chunks of data. That will improve the response to *Ctrl-C* but reduce the efficiency of the transfer